# why typedef is not working here?

Tags: c, typedef

I know simple definition of typedef :

```
typedef is a keyword in C to assign alternative names to types.
```

Following this definition I tried to implement typedef as following :

```
int main()
{
    typedef long mylong; //as per my knowledge after this statement mylong will be treated as long
    
    int long b;  // this works fine
    int mylong c; // but this gives error
}
```

I tried this on gcc. And following is the  error 
[image]

I know this error means I didn't get actual concept of typedef. Can anybody please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: You up voted simply a wrong answer.

Comment: Why? explain plz , I accepted as two or three answers are saying the same thing but this explains more to me. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I showed you the list of allowable sets of type specifiers. For example you can write either long or int long. So your question is reasonable. You could write in fact typedef long my_long; and then int my_long. In this case you would substitute type specifier long to int long. You are allowed to use either long or int long are not you? So the reason is simple: the Standard does not allow to do that. typedef is considered as a separate type specifier that is not included in any set of type specifiers.

Comment: You mean typedef long mylong; is not same as typedef long int mylong as per as answer is saying?

Comment: No I wanted to say other that typedef appends the list of allowed typespecifiers. It is not included in any multiset of the list. It adds one more row in the list. So it is not simply an alias for keyword long as it seems. If it would be so you could indeed to write int my_long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike `#define`, `typedef` is a mechanism for introducing a new name for a type, as opposed to a textual substitution.

Recall that types `long int`, `int long`, and `long` are three *synonyms* that refer to the same C type. When you use `typedef`, you make another synonym referring to that same type.

When you use it like this

```
mylong x = 123;
```

the usage is correct: `mylong` is used like a name of a type. However, when you try using it in combination with `int`, like this

```
int mylong x = 123;
```

the compiler reports an error because `int mylong` does not name a valid type. To the compiler it looks the same as if you wrote, say `int float x = 5` or `struct mystruct int z = ...`.

Answer (score 3):

When you omit the type in `C`, it's assumed `int`

So `typedef long mylong;` is the same as `typedef long int mylong;`.

Making the offending line be something like this:

```
int long int c;
```

Hence the error.

The typedef is a new type* (not text substitution for `long`). So you don't need to add an `int` to make a variable of that type. A simple `mylong c;` will suffice.

<sub>*Well, it's a bit more involved than that. The new type is in fact the same as a regular `long int`, and the two are interchangeable. But for sound domain logic, you should treat it as a new seperate type</sub>

Comment: But when i try to write int long int c;
directly then error is "two or more datatypes in declaration" 
not the same error as with typedef

Comment: that's because this explanation is incorrect. `typdef` is not a simple preprocessor-like substitution.

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar, that is the same problem regardless. You name two type for a variable. It just fails on a different parsing rule.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks for your nice explanation. But if int long int c; and int mylong c; are one and the same thing then compiler should give same error for both of statements. Isn't is?

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar, no it doesn't. The two are conceptually the same, yet there are more mechanisms involved in one than in the other.

Comment: So I was not wrong in understanding typedef, actullay I was wrong in understanding data types. I am worrying that I didn't know C data types as my placements are ahead.

Answer (score 3):

According tp paragraph 2 (Constraints) of section 6.7.2 Type specifiers of the C Standard

> Each list of type specifiers shall be **one** of the following
>   multisets...

```
— void
— char
— signed char
— unsigned char
— short, signed short, short int, or signed short int
— unsigned short, or unsigned short int
— int, signed, or signed int
— unsigned, or unsigned int
— long, signed long, long int, or signed long int
— unsigned long, or unsigned long int
— long long, signed long long, long long int, or
signed long long int
— unsigned long long, or unsigned long long int
— float
— double
— long double
— _Bool
— float _Complex
— double _Complex
— long double _Complex
— atomic type specifier
— struct or union specifier
— enum specifier
— typedef name
```

As you see the C Standard does not allow to combine `typedef name` with other type specifiers.

Comment: It means I can use typedef name alone only but not combining it with other datatype?

Comment: And amazing thing is that it is giving me different errors when I change the order mylong int c and int mylong c are giving totally different errors, couldn't getting it?

Comment: @A.s. Bhullar It depends on how the compiler parses a construction, what grammar rule will be shosen. For example you may write typedef long my_long;

int main(void) 
{
 int my_long = 0;

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand `long` / `short`.

```
typedef long mylong;
```

You said "typedef is a keyword in C to assign alternative names to **types**." `long` is actually not type - **`long int` is type.** C just allows you to leave out `int` when you're using `short`, `long` or `long long` So your statement is equal to

```
typedef long int mylong;
```

Comment: what ?? long is not a type but I have read so many text books that treat long and int as different types..

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar, they are different type. `long int` is one type, `int` is another type and `short int` is another type still. There is implicit casting done alot between them, but they _are_ different. Most people omit the `int` for `long` because `int` is the type assumed in `C` when only the `long` specifier is present.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for rapid answer ^°^